# rails loop through required attributes in a form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

In my Ruby on Rails project I have a module called Node. In that module I have different classes such as `playback`, `if`, `hangup`, etc. They are created using `Node::Playback`, for example. Each of these classes has different required attributes. Node has the following declaration as part of it:

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...Other irrelevant code
 class << self
  attr_accessor :required_attrs
  attr_accessor :optional_attrs

  def acts_as_node required_attrs=[], optional_attrs=[]
    @required_attrs = required_attrs
    @optional_attrs = optional_attrs
    (required_attrs + optional_attrs).each do |attr|
      attr_accessor attr
    end

    required_attrs.each do |attr|
      validates attr, presence: true
    end
  end
end
end
```

As an example, `playback`, declared as `class Node::Playback`, has the following in its model:

```
class Node::Playback < Node
  acts_as_node [ :body, :author ]
end
```

In my view for creating a playback node, I want to loop through all the required attributes, i.e. `[:body, :author]`. It is important that I do this dynamically and not hard code it because Node has many different classes, not just playback.

```
= form_for([@callflow, @new_node]) do |f|
  h2 | Fill All Required Attributes Below
  - @node_type.required_attrs.each do |ra|
    .form-group
      = f.label ra
      = f.text_area(ra)
  h2 | Fill Optional Attributes Below
  - @node_type.optional_attrs.each do |oa|
    .form-group
      = f.label oa
      /= f.text_area oa
  .form-group
    = f.submit class: 'btn btn-success'
```

In the above code, @node_type.required_attrs returned `[:body, :author]` when I byebugged it in the controller. I also checked that the elements in the array are of class 'Symbol'. `@new_node` was created using `Node.new(callflow: @callflow)` and `@node_type` was created using `"Node::Playback".constantize`

`f.label ra` would put the correct label in my view(ie. correctly put a label in my form when I comment out the line below it). 
However, when I did `f.text_area ra` or `f.text_area(ra)` it would say `undefined method body' for #<Node:0x00007f271df3bc18>`

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think your `acts_as_node` macro should be declared as `def self.acts_as_node required_attrs=[], optional_attrs=[]`

Answer (score 0):

`@new_node` appears to be an instance of `Node`.  I don't see a definition for `@node_type`, but based on the error, I'm assuming it's a `Node::Playback` instance.

The `Node` instance won't have the required attributes of `Node::Playback`, so when you ask the form renderer `f` (which represents a `Node` instance) to render the required attribute `ra` of a `Node::Playback` instance you're getting the error.

Try this instead:

```
= form_for([@callflow, @new_node]) do |f|
  h2 | Fill All Required Attributes Below
  - f.object.required_attrs.each do |ra|
    .form-group
      = f.label ra
      = f.text_area(ra)
```

Then make sure that the `@new_node` instance is of the appropriate type (e.g. `Node::Playback`)